# Membership.GetUserNameByEmail not returning user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

I'm calling

```
Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(email)
```

but it's returning null even when I have an email in the AspNetUsers table.
Is this the table that this method checks?

Comment: Are you using Asp.Net Identity or `MembershipProvider`? these are 2 different incompatible systems.

Comment: I got it by usermanager finbyemail()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an Username by email from AspNetUsers table, you can use this:

```
string username= db.AspNetUsers.Where(a => a.Email == email).FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

For `Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(email)` you need to properly configure your membership in Web.config file. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx) article.